# C++ Read binary file into vector of custom class

Tags: c++, vector

I am trying to dump some data into a binary file, then load it from somewhere else, but I keep getting Access Violation read errors, or _Block_Type_Is_Valid (pHead->nBlockUse) errors upon trying to read the saved file.

This is the code for saving the file:

```
ofstream ofs(filename, ios_base::out | ios_base::binary);
// Write how many pop this file includes.
ofs.write((char*)&pop_size, sizeof(int));

// And the vectors
ofs.write((char*)&tmp_p[0], (tmp_p.size() * sizeof(TSOP)) );
ofs.close();
```

This is the reading method (I've tried several combinations):

```
ifstream ifs;
ifs.open(filename, ios_base::in | ios_base::binary);
int pop_size = -1;
ifs.read((char*)&pop_size, sizeof(int));
ifs.read(reinterpret_cast<char *>(&tmp_p[0]), sizeof(TSOP) * tmp_p.size());
ifs.close();
```

(I also tried saving, and reading each element in a loop, and instead of reinterpret_cast I just used (char*), nothing worked..)

The vectors contains elements of the class TSOP, which looks like this:

```
class TSOP 
{
public:
    TSOP();
    virtual ~TSOP();

    void show();

    TIndividual     indiv;
    vector <TIndividual> indiv_M;
    vector <double> namda;    
    vector <double> namda_t;    
    vector <int>    table;     // the vector for the indexes of neighboring subproblems

    bool            updated;

    void  operator=(const TSOP&sub2);
};
```

And the TIndividual:

```
class TIndividual{
public:
    TIndividual();
    virtual ~TIndividual();

    vector <double> x_var;
    //boost::dynamic_bitset<> x_var_bits;
    //std::bitset<> x_var_bits2;
    vector <double> y_obj;
    vector <double> y_obj_n;
    vector <double> y_blc;
    //for constraints
    vector <double> y_bio;
    double y_bio_sum;
    bool feasible;
    //for constraints

    //for NSGA-III
    int pi_idx;
    double d;
    bool dominated;
    //short dominateds;

    void   rnd_init();
    void   obj_eval(int count_index_start = 0);
    void   calc_balance();

    bool   operator<(const TIndividual &ind2);
    bool   operator>(const TIndividual &ind2);
    bool   operator==(const TIndividual &ind2);
    void   operator=(const TIndividual &ind2);

    void show_objective();
    void show_variable();

    long id;


    double var;
};
```

I read that there could be problem with pointers and strings when saving binary files, but there aren't any pointers or strings in these classes.
It's mostly made up from vectors, ints and doubles.

By using cout, I am able to read the first int for the pop_size, then upon attempting to read the first element of the saved vector, it crashes.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Just briefly reading over your problem, it seems to me that you don' really know what your problem is and it is one of those "debug my code" questions. You've got alot of factors, reading the file, writing the file, serializing to binary, deserializing it, vectors, etc. Try to narrow down your problem. Why not see if your class type serializes to binary without writing it out to file, eliminating anything that writing to file would introduce. If that test passes, move on to deserializing, then next to file and back. Narrow it down.

Comment: If you write the `vector`, mirror image from it's internal representation, you may only get the "header" and not the data. Search the internet for "C++ serialization library".

Comment: `ofs.write((char*)&tmp_p[0], (tmp_p.size() * sizeof(TSOP)) );` you can't do this. You need to properly serialize.

Comment: If you have `vector<int> tmp;` then you can use the `write` method on `vector`, because `sizeof(int)` is always 4 bytes. But this method doesn't work with `vector<TSOP> tmp;`. Note that `sizeof(TSOP)` is only about 20 bytes. But each `TSOP` index may refer to several gigabytes of data. You have to decide which data you want to save and write it separately.